# Dónde se encuentra el directorio ./examples de la guía de Kivy

Tags: android, programación-móvil, kivy

Estoy tratando de acceder a los [ejemplos](https://kivy.org/docs/gettingstarted/examples.html) de la guia [Getting Started](https://kivy.org/docs/gettingstarted/) de Kivy, pero no sé dónde están los directorios que me ponen.
¿Alguien sabe dónde están?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si hablasmos de Windows, los ejemplos deben estar dentro del directorio donde tienes instalado la versión de Python con la que usas Kivy, en concreto en la carpeta `share`:

La ruta es algo así:

```
C:\Users\Nombre_usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\share\kivy-examples
            ^^^^^^
   Cambiar esto apropiadamente
```

Puede depender de la versión del sistema que uses o si no instalastes Python en la ruta por defecto. De todas formas basta con localizar el directorio donde tengas Python instalado e ir a la carpeta `share`.

si estamos en Linux se debe instalar los ejemplos de forma independiente, por ejemplo para Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install kivy-examples
```

Posteriormente los encontramos en:

```
/usr/share/kivi-examples/
```

Otra opción es descargarte los ejemplos directamente del [repositorio de GitHub](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master/examples).

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de Linux, para Debian 10, con Python3, Kivy 1.11.1 tengo la siguiente ruta:

```
 $HOME/.local/share/kivy-examples/
```